# Step Functions Filter DynamoDB JSON Array

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I have the following output in a task result and trying to apply result selector to it.

```
{
 "data": {
  "events": [
    {
      "system": {
        "S": "PRIMARY"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}

Apply this result selector:

```
{"events.$":"$.data.events[?(@.system.S == PRIMARY)]"}
```

However it returns no results.

If I reformat the task result to be standard JSON instead of Dynamo DB and change the query to

```
{"events.$":"$.data.events[?(@.system == PRIMARY)]"}
```

the filtering will work. But trying to avoid a lambda in my state machine just to unmarshall the dynamodb response

Comment: What do you mean by "standard JSON"? I believe you should surround `PRIMARY` with single quotes for it to be treated as a string, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I mean unmarshalled Dynamo DB JSON. Unfortunately no difference with changing the variable to a string

Comment: What does this umarshalled JSON look like?

Comment: https://blog.awsfundamentals.com/aws-dynamodb-data-types

Answer (score 0):

Gonna make a guess at this one, as i'm not sure if `events` is originating from DynamoDB or elsewhere, if its DynamoDB give it a try:

```
{"events.L.$":"$.data.events[?(@.system.S == PRIMARY)]"}
```

Comment: Events is originating from Dynamo DB, sadly no difference withe the .L added

Comment: Sorry I placed it at the wrong side, let me update it. Try it now

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question about events. This is in the result selector so the events.$ is where I'm inserting the result of the task into.

Comment: I believe it is a bug in step functions, as this filter:
    $..data.events[?(@.defaultSystem.S=="GREEN")]

works with the same input on https://jsonpath.com/ but doesn't work on step functions flow simulator